# JavaScript - When if statement is true, code doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I have 3 different inputs for the user - Day/Month/Year, and I'm trying to run an if statement to check if the month is Jan/Feb (1 or 2), and then if it subtracts 1 from the year. My if statement is:

```
if (month == 1 || month == 2) {
    if (month == 1) {
        year = Number(year) - 1;
    }
    else if (month == 2) {
        year = Number(year) - 1;
    }
}
```

This is my first time trying to use javascript and it's very frustrating!
As you can see my code runs when I have month = 3, but as soon as I change it to 1 or 2 it no longer executes...
[image]

Comment: Post code instead of images

Comment: Post your code as text not images.

Comment: Or better yet put the code in the second screenshot into a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: doesn't excute means there is no output, or is still shows the wrong output?

Comment: @mahlatse and when question is edited, downvotes can be altered...

Comment: @epascarello I remember that there was a timer on reversing votes, after x amount of time , all votes are locked.

Comment: @mahlatse if there is an edit, you can change your vote.

Comment: @epascarello, that assumes that you are always on SO like a halk waiting for downvoted questions to be edited? I doubt most new users understand that fact, in most cases you just find downvotes on a question without any feedback

Comment: @mahlatse been on the site since the beginning, it is never going to change. lol, and the people you are complaining to are not going to come and see your comment like you just said since they will not come back. lol

Comment: @epascarello , there should be a better way to do this, maybe force users to specify a reason if the user is new

Comment: @mahlatse Search meta.... this is the wrong place to talk about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because you convert the year to a string and than after than you use string operations on the number. The error in your console should clearly state it.

```
year = Number(year) - 1
...
var century = year.substring(0,2)
```

so if you are going to do string actions on it, than you need to convert the number back to a string.

So either you do

```
year = (Number(year) - 1).toString()
```

or

```
var century = year.toString().substring(0,2)
```

In the end, the error "Uncaught TypeError: year.substring is not a function" should have been in your developer [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/).

Answer (score -1):

I've just try it on JSFidddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var month=1;
  var year ='2018';


  if ((month == 1) || (month == 2)) {
        if (month == 1) {
            year = Number(year) - 1;
        }
        else if (month == 2) {
            year = Number(year) - 1;
        }   
    }
  alert(year);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/0zpu2j34/1/)